# MySQL IF INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have the following query:

IF (some statement) THEN
   INSERT ...
ELSE
   UPDATE ...

My question is how can I check which action took place?
Let's say I want to print 1 if it was an INSERT or 2 if UPDATE using php.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one already, create a column that is populated on insert and not changed during updates (`create_time` would be a suggestion)

then... after insert, compare the time difference with the current time...  if the time difference is within a few seconds (or whatever threshold seems best to you) then the operation was an insert, otherwise it was an update

```
select if( timestampdiff( second, create_time, now() ) <= 3, 1, 2) from...
```

Comment: This is a nice joke ;-)